# How to fetch all images under a folder in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media

I want to make a image gallery (for this there are some free and paid version available) but to show them as per Month wise there is no such  free extension.

- mainfolder

  - May

    - someimage.jpg
    - someimage.jpg
  - June

    - ...

So i thought to create folder having name as month then fetch all images under them and using some jquery i can make a gallery.

I created the above idea on localhost in PHP but in magento i am new , no idea from where to start.

In `some_custom.phtml`

```
$mypath3 = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK).'media/mediamadd/';
$dirpass = scandir($mypath3);  
print_r($dirpass);  // this gives nothing
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as starting point ... you can get all images from your folders in this way:

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// adjust this to your folder
$root = './mainfolder/' . date('n');
$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
);

foreach ($iterator as $path => $item) {
    if ($item->isFile() && $item->getExtension() == 'jpg') {
        // your logic here for $path
    }
}
```

Folder structure would be

> - mainfolder
>
>   - 1
>   - ...
>   - 12

Example is for standalone usage, but you can use this code in your modules block class.

Comment: can you plz tell me how to pass `http://websitename.com/media/mediamadd/`  in place of `$root` in RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Comment: as i got this error `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(http://websitename.com/media/mediamadd/): failed to open dir: not implemented`

Comment: Try to remove domain name ... just use `./media/mediamadd/ . date('n') `. For `date('n')` you have to create subfolders 1-12.

Comment: `$root = 'media/mediamadd/';`  this path works.

Comment: `what is date('n')`     is n=1 means folder having name 1 and n=2 means folder having name 2

Comment: `date('n')` gives you the number of current month ... so folder for january is 1, february 2 ....

Comment: ok. one more help how i can get only image name as print_r gives  `SplFileInfo Object ( [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => media/mediamadd/English/May_2016 (2).jpg [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => May_2016 (2).jpg )`

Comment: `$item->getFilename()` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much . Is there any way to get image title as well.

Comment: No, not with this method. Have some ideas that could make it, but thats far out of scope of this question :)

Comment: Ok No issue , I will try at my end to find. Thank You again for help and knowledge